# The "addFront" function looks awfully procedural (i.e., not declarative)

Tags: alloy

On page 10 of the book *Software Abstractions* it emphasizes the declarative nature of Alloy:

> Alloy is declarative, and describes how to check whether a change of
>   state is valid, by comparing the before and after values.

On page 9 is an example of adding a new email address book. The example shows how the state of a book after an "add" differs from the state of the book before the add. Nice - very declarative indeed!

On page 135 is an example of a parameterized "list" module. The example has a function "addFront":

```
fun List.addFront (e: t): List {
    { p: List | p.next = this and p.element = e } }
```

That doesn't look very declarative to me. To be declarative I would expect the parameter list to contain a before and after list and I would expect the code to show how the state of the list after an "addFront" differs from the state of the list before the "addFront" (just like book example).

Why is addFront written in a procedural manner? Isn't it violating the declarative nature of Alloy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declarative means (to me) that rather than explaining how the computation happens step by step, you give an observation about the computation. That's what this function does: it says that if you look at the result of addFront, you'll find that its next field holds the input list and its element field holds the given element. The set comprehension (in combination with the canonicalization fact, given in the book but not shown here) says "return the list p such that ...".

Perhaps what seems non declarative to you in this case is that the Alloy looks very much like the code you'd have in a functional language such as ML. But that code would also seem to me to be declarative in nature -- and in fact the term "declarative" has been widely used to describe functional languages for this reason.

I should also note that while Alloy is indeed designed to support declarative modeling, and I believe that for complex state transitions a declarative approach is often best, I don't think that means that there is necessarily anything wrong with a more operational form of description (see Pamela Zave's early [paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=809737&dl=ACM&coll=DL&CFID=859564121&CFTOKEN=98587746) on this). What's problematic in a model is the presence of details that are of no significance to the behavior, but are included because of weaknesses in the modeling language, or because the modeler is unwittingly introducing implementation concerns.

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel - great!